# Check to see if directory/file exist before creating?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Currently this is my code:

```
    private void writeToSDFile(){

        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");


        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
            pw.println(d8 + d7 + ":" + d6 + d5 + ":" + d4 + d3 + ":" + d2 + d1);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            f.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                    " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Basically, I would like to know if there's a way (maybe by the use of an if statement) to only create the file/directory if they DONT exist. At the moment, it recreates them both each time writetoSDCard() is called.

All I want to do is keep appending the data to the end of the file. Just for reference it'd  be stored like this: 00:00:00:00

Thanks :)

Also, while I'm here, just a quick question, is there a way for the program to say, read a list of 2 digit numbers from a txt document, then add them together? eg
20
20
30
So result on screen is 70? I haven't really found anything like this around  :/

Comment: tried using `exists()` on your `dir`?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
String FOLDERNAME="/download";
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDERNAME);
if(!dir.exists())
{
dir.mkdir();
}
```

copy and past

```
private void writeToSDFile(){

        String FOLDERNAME="/download";
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDERNAME);
        if(!dir.exists())
        {
        dir.mkdir();
        }

    File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");


    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println(d8 + d7 + ":" + d6 + d5 + ":" + d4 + d3 + ":" + d2 + d1);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

**/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT
For File**

```
   File f;
  f=new File(dir, "myData.txt");
  if(!f.exists())
  {
  f.createNewFile();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine for the directory. Is there a way to do the same with a file? I tried

        File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");
     if(!file.exists()){
      file.createNewFile();
     }
but it doesnt like that

Comment: :/ It still creates a new file. It doesnt append the old file.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirpath";
File myDirectory = new File(path);
    if(!myDirectory.isDirectory()){
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by calling `exists()` method for `dir/file` or you can go for particular also like `isDirectory()` or `isFile()`.

```
File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

or 

if(!dir.isDirectory())
        dir.mkdirs();
```

same way you can do for file also